# sh: variable substitution with heredoc

Tags: sh

```
 cat "${pos}" | /usr/bin/iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8  | uniq | sed -En "/^CLIENT_ID.*/!p" | while read line
do
 .....
......

cat >> "$TMPFILE" << EOF
INSERT INTO ......;
EOF

done
```

As you can see each iteration writes a SQL statement to a tmp-file.
I launched this script from a regular interactive shell and got the expected output.  Launched from a cron job - nothing.

After investigating I found a problem. When I use `"$TMPFILE"` without `""` the script works ok. Why does this happen?

OS: FreeBSD, bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `cron` doesn't source all the files that a login shell does, so you will end up with different settings for environment variables. Could be the path `$TMPFILE` is pointing to contains spaces when run from `cron` for example.

Also, on some systems (depending on setup), `cron` uses a different shell. So if you start your script from command line, for example `/usr/bin/sh` might be used, whereas when started by `cron`, `/bin/sh` is used. (I have no experience with *BSD, but I have observed this on linux.)

Comment: Crontab contain needed `PATH`, and line in crontab like `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh _path_to_script/script.sh`. Script also contain `PATH, LANG,LC_*` and so on.

Comment: heh, have found problem. My mistake in heredoc syntax. Correct way is `cat >> "$TMPFILE" <<EOF` without space.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it worked when started manually then?

Comment: @Andry That doesn't sound right; I'm not aware of any shell which does not allow a space between `<<` and the delimiter.

Comment: @chepner This sounds true. You can try yourself.